# not commutative symmetric vs strong symmetric spaces

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let M be a von Neumann algebra  with semi-finite normal faithful trace $\tau$, $S(M)$ is space of all measurable operators introduced by I.Segal.
For the self-adjoint measurable operator $X\eta M$ consider spectral function 
$\chi_{[s,\infty)}(X)$, its trace spectral or distribution function $d_X(s)=\tau(\chi_{[s,\infty)}(X))$ and not increasing re-arrangement function or singular value function define as $\mu(t,X)=\inf\{s\geq 0 | d_{|X|}(s)\leq t\}, t\geq 0$. 
Hardy function is 
$h(t,X)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \mu(s,|X|) ds$.
For the $X, Y\in S(M)$, $Y\prec X$ ( $Y\prec \prec X$) if $\mu(t,Y)\leq \mu(t,X)$ ($h(t,Y)\leq h(t,X)$) for any $t\geq 0$.

The Banach space $E\in S(M)$ with norm $||.||_E$ is called non commutative symmetric if together with $X\in E$ it contains $Y\in S(M)$ when $Y\prec X$; in addition norm inequality $||Y||_E\leq ||X||_E$ holds.
The space $E$ is called strongly symmetric if $E$ is symmetric and in addition to $X,Y\in E$, $Y\prec\prec X$ implies  $||Y||_E\leq ||X||_E$.
Any example of non commutative symmetric and not strongly symmetric space?

Comment: Please go to help and read "How do I ask a good question?".

Comment: In particular, define your terms: specify which objects live in which spaces; and so forth

Comment: Added all formal definition

Answer (score 1):

Take E to be Dixmier-Macev ideal. That is,

$$E=\{A\in M: \sup_{t>0}\frac1{\log(t+1)}\int_0^t\mu(s,X)ds<\infty\}.$$
Take $F$ to be weak $L_1$ ideal, that is
$$F=\{A\in M: \sup_{t>0}t\mu(t,A)<\infty\}.$$
Clearly, $F\subset E$ and it is known that F is not dense in E. Take H to be the closure of F in E. This answers your question.